# Vagrant: ping not working while ssh works

Tags: vagrant

I have created vagrant box by using these settings:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
  config.vm.define 'test2' do |machine|
    machine.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    machine.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.33.23"
    machine.disksize.size = "15GB"
    machine.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/root/data"
    machine.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = 'test2'
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 3072]
      v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/data", "1"]
    end
  end
```

end

I can connect to this box via ssh, but when I try to ping it like this:

```
ping 192.168.33.23
```

It throws to me timeout error. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh and ping use different ports, probably when trying to ping  that IP, server probably denies public access. Try to use telnet with specific port instead to see if port is opened and accessible.

Comment: strange. Telnet not working. However, `vagrant ssh test2` works